# HTML form with windows cyrillic button's names doesn't work on OSX

Tags: php, html, forms, macos, cyrillic

I installed a site locally on OSX. The site was developed under windows and have cyrillic (Windows) encoding for some string values.

I noted that some buttons with cyrillic values wouldn't work until I change the value to english. The button looks for this, for example:

```
<form action="{$REQUEST_URI}" method="POST" name="addForm" id="addForm">
...
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="addDo" value="Добавить" class="btn"></td>
...
</form>
```

and in php I get void (false) string here:

```
$addDo = $_POST['addDo'];
if($addDo)
...
```

When I change it to

```
 <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="addDo" value="Add" class="btn"></td>
```

It starts to work properly.

Why can this happen? 
The site is not my to change, therefore the question is **How can I change my OSX setup to make this site works like on Windows?**

P.S. This html file is fetched from php module by smarty:

```
$smarty->fetch('login.html');
```

Comment: So you are only looking for a fix to get this working client-side on your own machine? Is the page not used by other users, that would likely have the same problem if they are on OSX?

Comment: @CBroe, I don't think that there will be other users (the once, which want to install site locally) with OSX. But if the fix is not possible at my machine then fix for the server side could also be useful.

Comment: Well at the server-side this should be fixed by porting the whole application to a universally understood character encoding like UTF-8. But this might involve some more work then just switching one single setting.

Comment: what is your html document header? could you show all meta tags there? does it include `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">`?

Comment: @KimAlexander, there are no header, since it is the file, which is fetched by smarty. I tried to add your header there with no effect.

Comment: show me your full html document or link to the page

Comment: @KimAlexander, https://braingames.ru

Comment: your site has `Content-Type:text/html` in header response, you can try to replace it to  `Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8`

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['addDo'])` return ?

Comment: Use the webserver options to set correct charset header, since all text contents must get it.

Comment: @AndréDaniel, what do you mean? Doesn't "in php I get void (false) string here" answers your question?

Comment: @klm123 yes it answers the question... and doesn't look good; I'll try on my own machine.

Comment: I have to worn you, that though the bounty is ending only tomorrow I won't be able to award it anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set my php configuration as well.
Just go to php.ini and change from

```
default-charset="utf-8"
```

to

```
default-charset="windows-1251"
```

restart the local server - and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

In your php application you can try to set html header:

`header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`

or

`header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=windows-1251");`

somewhere before your:

`$smarty->fetch('login.html');`

Comment: windows-1251 changes nothing. utf-8 allows me to use button, but text of the button and the entire site becomes unreadable.

Comment: so, you can convert your data source from 1251 to UTF-8 page by page, and table by table if you use database. I think it can take some time but it is reasonable. and/or you can search settings in your browser under OSX to set windows-1251 as default code page. do you use safari? try to install chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Building webpages should use either HTML entities (`&#8221;`), or UTF-8 encoding.  You have used Windows-1251 to create this page.  You may need to re-export the entire site from windows with a UTF-8 codepage (NOT MUTF-8), or import the Windows-1251 codepage to this OSX machine.

Comment: How do I import the Windows-1252 codepage to this OSX machine?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you just want to make site work locally you should firstly convert all your files to UTF-8 using iconv:

```
iconv -f CP-1251 -t UTF-8 original_file.html > utf8_file.html
```

Secondly, you need to convert databases (if they're used) to same UTF-8:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And then you should set correct header before sending results to browser:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Let me know if this works for you.